# Is there any way to hide the "Try it out" option for specific API using OpenAPI 3 in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

We can hide **"Try it out"** option for Methods like GET,PATCH,POST, etc... by adding

`springdoc.swagger-ui.supportedSubmitMethods = Array=["get", "put", "post","patch"]`
in Application.properties file.

and hide it for all Api by adding `springdoc.swagger-ui.tryItOutEnabled = true`

We want to hide it for a specific API.

1. Is there any way to hide this by using `OpenApi 3` in Spring Boot?
2. Can hide the whole `Parameter` part if there is no parameter defined in API?

[image]